How to chown files and folders on the SD card, first attempts leaves to Permission denied
I have installed GraphHopper with Termux. I have ~/storage/shared pointing to my SD card:
~ $ ls -l storage/
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 u0_a212 u0_a212 34 Oct 30 12:45 dcim -> /storage/emulated/0/DCIM
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 u0_a212 u0_a212 34 Oct 30 12:45 downloads -> /storage/emulated/0/Download
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 u0_a212 u0_a212 34 Oct 30 12:45 movies -> /storage/emulated/0/Movies
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 u0_a212 u0_a212 34 Oct 30 12:45 music -> /storage/emulated/0/Music
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 u0_a212 u0_a212 34 Oct 30 12:45 pictures -> /storage/emulated/0/Pictures
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 u0_a212 u0_a212 34 Oct 30 12:45 shared -> /storage/emulated/0

My user is u0_a212 and here are the links to the cache on the SD card:
~ $ ls -l graphhopper
total 44767
-rw-------. 1 u0_a212 u0_a212     3448 Oct 30 12:34 config.yml
drwxr-xr-x. 2 u0_a212 u0_a212     3452 Oct 30 09:45 custom_models
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 u0_a212 u0_a212       82 Oct 29 18:11 europe -> /data/data/com.termux/files/home/storage/shared/Documents/graphhopper/europe
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 u0_a212 u0_a212       98 Oct 29 18:11 graph-cache -> /data/data/com.termux/files/home/storage/shared/Documents/graphhopper/graph-cache
-rw-------. 1 u0_a212 u0_a212 45780835 May  5 17:52 graphhopper-web-9.1.jar
drwx------. 2 u0_a212 u0_a212     3452 Oct 30 09:40 logs

The problem is here:
~ $ ls -dl /data/data/com.termux/files/home/storage/shared/Documents/graphhopper/graph-cache
drwx------. 2 u0_a189 u0_a189 3452 Oct 30 12:47 /data/data/com.termux/files/home/storage/shared/Documents/graphhopper/graph-cache
~ $ ls -l /data/data/com.termux/files/home/storage/shared/Documents/graphhopper/graph-cache
ls: cannot open directory '/data/data/com.termux/files/home/storage/shared/Documents/graphhopper/graph-cache': Permission denied

Unexpectedly, from Android root, the user is not the same. And if I try to change it with chown, I get a Permission denied.
Why the user is different? Is there a solution to change it?
